# Is satire used anywhere in "The Story of How Basat Killed Goggle-Eye"?

Tags: turkish-language, the-book-of-dede-korkut

Is satire used anywhere in the story "The Story of How Basat Killed Goggle-Eye"?

The story is from The Book of Dede Korkut.

Comment: A cursory reread (of the Penguin edition of Geoffrey Lewis) doesn't seem to show any satire to me, but that proves nothing.  Do you have any hints about what might be satirical?

Comment: Maybe towards the end where Basat kills Goggle-Eye?

Comment: Hi, is that story included in the [online version](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Book_of_Dede_Korkut)?

Comment: @Tsundoku No, it seems not. The story in question is item 8 in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Dede_Korkut#Synopses).

Comment: Thank you for inducing me to reread this delightful story.  But your question is vague.  What does "satire" mean in the context of your question, and what particular passages are you asking about?